# How to make a "dynamic" etc/fstab

Tags: boot, partition, fstab, usb-drive

I have manually installed linux on a USB drive.
It works and boots up when I plug the drive into the original computer.

The problem comes when the drive is on a different computer or there are other drives plugged in and my USB is NOT /dev/sdb.
I then get an error that the root drive can not be mounted because etc/fstab says root is /dev/sdb1.

How can I make the /etc/fstab either change on bootup or make it automatically use the partition that the kernel is in (my root partition)?

Comment: Note that your kernel is not on your root partition, but instead on your /boot partition.

Comment: @mashuptwice That's true normally - I built an LFS system and put it all in the same partition for no real reason

Comment: Well, there is always an edgecase

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also identify the partitions with their UUIDs

The **U**nique **U**niversal **ID**entifier is, as the name implies, unique and never changes. It even stays the same when using the media on a different computer.

You can use UUIDs instead of `/dev/sdx` by editing `/etc/fstab`

Note that you need to run the following commands as root.

1. Identify your partition with `lsblk`, e.g. /dev/sda1
2. Get the partitions UUID via `blkid`
3. Edit /etc/fstab and replace /dev/sda1 with the UUID as following

Before:

```
/dev/sda1          /boot           vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro   0 2
```

After:

```
UUID=5cd7485d-d22e-4860-bdb5-753d5456714a          /boot           vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro   0 2
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed